Is the class of separable extensions distinguished?
We know, thanks to embeddings, that the class of separable extensions verified the property of the fields tower. That is, in a fields tower $K\subseteq F\subseteq E$, it is true that: $E/K$ is separable if and only if $E/F$ and $F/K$ are separable.
But what can we say about the other properties required to be a distinguished class of extensions? Do they verify?
I was wondering about this after reading that Galois extensions (that is, normal separable extensions) do verify the multiplicative property.
And if they are not, what simple examples can I find?

Lang (among others), uses "distinguished class of extensions", but I do not think it is a widely-used term. A class of extension fields is "distinguished" if and only if:

If $K\subseteq F\subseteq E$, then $E/K$ is in the class if and only if both $E/F$ and $F/K$ are in the class.
If $K\subseteq E$ is in the class, and $L$ is any other extension of $K$, with $E$ and $L$ contained in some common field $F$, then $EL/L$ is in the class.
If $K\subseteq E$ and $K\subseteq L$ are two extensions in the class, with both $E$ and $L$ contained in some common field $F$, then $EL/K$ is in the class.

Note that an extension $E/K$ is separable if and only if every $a\in E$ is separable over $K$ (its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots), if and only if there exists a family $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$ of elements of $E$ such that each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $K$, and $E=K(\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in i})$.
From these facts, the three conditions follow easily. You already know 1. For 2, let $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of elements of $E$ with $E=K(\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I})$, each $\alpha_i$ separable over $K$. Then the $\alpha_i$ are also separable over $L$, and clearly $EL = L(\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I})$, so $EL/L$ is separable.
Now 3 follows from 1 and 2: Since $L/K$ is separable, so is $EL/E$ by 2; then $EL/E$ and $E/K$ are separable, so by 1 we have that $EL/K$ is separable.

Perfect. Thanks.
